# Setting a site-wide variable for text-field max length - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

First of all, I want to ask forgiveness if this question is too broad.

But I'm still a little new to Rails and want to set a max length 50 chars for text fields when I edit certain titles of certain records. I know that in every one of them, I could just do something like:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, maxlength: 50 %>
```

But I'd really like to do something more like:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, maxlength: HEADER_MAX_LENGTH %>
```

where `HEADER_MAX_LENGTH` is a variable that I can re-use in other forms in other views.  Is there a certain place I can make such a variable to help keep my code DRY?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I initially had the `f.text_field` tags syntax wrong.  Fixed 'em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an entry in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.header_max_length = 50
```

And use this while creating forms:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, nil, maxlength: Rails.application.config.header_max_length %>
```

To make it more DRY you could create a helper method for a custom `text_field_with_maxlength` or create a [custom FormBuilder](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#customizing-form-builders).